# deprecated Warning - where parameter in mataplotlib library

Tags: python, matplotlib

```py
Ages = [19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27]

python = [23000,30000,40000,50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000]
Java  = [15000,20000,25000,35000,40000,50000,90000,100000,300000]


pl.plot(Ages,python,label="Python developer") 
pl.plot(Ages,Java,label="Java developer") 

pl.fill_between(Ages,python,Java,where= (python > Java), alpha=0.5, color="blue" , label="greater than")
pl.fill_between(Ages,python,Java,where= (python < Java), alpha=0.5, color="red" , label="less than")


pl.title("Fill area on line plots")   
pl.legend(loc="upper left")
pl.show()
```

I am getting deprecation warning & also i didnt get the red margin when python value less than Java value.. Below i have mentioned error & screenshot of output...

Error:

```
matplot.py:143: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The parameter where must have the same size as x in fill_between(). This will become an error in future versions of Matplotlib.
  pl.fill_between(Ages,python,Java,where= (python > Java), alpha=0.5, color="blue" , label="greater than")
matplot.py:144: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The parameter where must have the same size as x in fill_between(). This will become an error in future versions of Matplotlib.
  pl.fill_between(Ages,python,Java,where= (python < Java), alpha=0.5, color="red" , label="less than")
```

Output:

[image: Output screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This deprecation warning is mainly to pinpoint that the `where` parameter doesn't have the same number of arguments as the other arrays. Usually it hints at unwanted behavior. Before, such error was ignored.

The `where` parameter is expected to have one `True/False` value for each point on the plot.

In this case, the expression `python < Java` has just one single value, as both are regular Python lists. To obtain a list of individual boolean values, you either need to create that list more manually `[p < j for p, j in zip(python, Java)]`. Or change everything to numpy arrays, and let its [vectorization and broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) take care of creating the array of boolean values.

Note that you need an extra parameter, `interpolate=True` to handle the line segments where the value for one point is `True` while the value for the other is `False`.

Here is the code with the lists changed to numpy arrays (`python > Java` then also returns an array) and `interpolate=True` set.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Ages = np.array([19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27])

python = np.array([23000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 90000, 100000])
Java = np.array([15000, 20000, 25000, 35000, 40000, 50000, 90000, 100000, 300000])

plt.plot(Ages, python, label="Python developer")
plt.plot(Ages, Java, label="Java developer")

plt.fill_between(Ages, python, Java, where=(python > Java), interpolate=True,
                 alpha=0.5, color="blue", label="greater than")
plt.fill_between(Ages, python, Java, where=(python < Java), interpolate=True,
                 alpha=0.5, color="red", label="less than")
plt.title("Fill area on line plots")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]